# binary floating point perform substraction and addition

Tags: arithmetic, binary-operations, floating-point, binary-programming

if $x=1.0e38=1.0 * 10^{38}$ and $y=3.0$ 
i want to find $ (x-x)+y $ and $(x+y)-x$ 
i think the value of (x-x)+y will be just substract $x-x=0 + y=3.0 = 3.0$ 
but how can i perfom addition of different base? $(x+y)-x$ 
i think the idea is addition $(x+y)$ then substract $-x$ using floating point, i tried to convert $y=3.0$ to binary such as $1.1 * 2^1$ 
but how about $10^{38}$ to binary ?

Comment: So you have defined two numbers, $x=10^{38}$ and $y=3$. And $(x-x)+y = (x+y)-x = y = 3$. Why do you ask about addition in a different base? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MattiP. i m not sure how can i find $(x+y)-x$ , the addition of $x=10^{38}$ and 　$ y=3.0$ ? i think i need to change it to floating point to perform the addition, but how  can i change  $10^{38}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define what floating point format you are using.  Standard [IEEE $64-$bit floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers)  assigns $53$ bits to the mantissa, giving a precision of about $16$ decimal digits.  $10^{38}$ will be represented by some $53$ bit mantissa times a binary exponent.  To add to that, you have to match the exponents, and $3.0$ will be shifted far to the right, which means in floating point $10^{38}+3.0=10^{38}$ exactly and when you subtract off $10^{38}$ you will get $0$.  As long as the larger number is at least $10^{16}$ times the smaller this will happen.

Comment: @RossMIlikan thankyou this is IEEE 754bit floating point. Thankyou so much for the helpful answer!!! For IEEE 754 mantissa 23 bits and eksponent 8 bits, here i need to shift 3 to match the eksponent 1*$10^{38}$ , such as $0.0000000000....3 $ * $10^{38}$ then we add so it produce $10^{38}$ , is this because the mantissa only has 23 bits , so its overflow(?) and because eksponent is 38 +127 it is overflow(?)

Comment: The IEEE standard has several word lengths defined  Most implementations use binary, and these days:$64$ bits is common..  Please define which standard you are using.  There are decimal versions as well, but I don't see any with $23$ digits.  In any case, the shift will probably be enough for the $3.0$ to disappear-there is no point to the problem otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a moot point.  Unless you are willing to use an 'unlimited precision' software package, for any floating-point system with a reasonable number of digits in the mantissa (in any base you like), the digits of '$3.0$' will be shifted so far to the right of the radix point of '$1.0*10^{38}$' as to be dropped completely, hence the calculated value of '$(x+y)-x$' will end up as zero.

Comment: thankyou so much, this really helpful, but do i need to change $10^38 $ to binary first? In order to get the mantissa? And then change 3.0 to binary and shift 3.0 so it has $10^{38}$ too? And perform the addition?